# Tuple item processing for selenium automation - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, tuples

I have a list of multiple tuples and each tuple further has multiple items and i want to process the items of each tuples into application using selenium web driver

```
list_of_tuple = [('New year offer', 'Avaliabe upto 31 dec', 'ram@test.com', '02/02/2021'), ('Dipawali offer', '20% off dec', 'jyo@test.com', '05/19/2021'), ('Xmas', '50% of clothes', 'krsih@test.com', '11/11/2021'), ('New year offer', 'Available unto 31 Dec', 'ram@test.com', '02/02/2021')]
```

And the scenario is like this:
There are four text fields in a web application, and I want to enter (process) the each items (4 items in this case) of an induvial tuple into respective text field and I want to repeat this multiple times

How can I achieve this? please help

Regards,
Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # driver object

field1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="field1"]') # X-Path of field 1
field2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="field2"]') # X-Path of field 2
field3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="field3"]') # X-Path of field 3
field4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="field4"]') # X-Path of field 4
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit"]') # X-Path of submit

for i in list_of_tuples :
    field1.send_keys(i[0]) 
    field2.send_keys(i[1])
    field3.send_keys(i[2])
    field4.send_keys(i[3])
    submit.click() # Sending click to the submit button.
```